# Как поверх pdf вывести надпись на кирилице? tfpdf, fpdi

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Как по нажатию на кнопку в новом pdf вывести дату и содержимое файла file.pdf с кирилической записью? Нашел варианты которые работают по отдельности, если обект `new Fpdi()` может работать с существующим pdf, но не может кирилицу вывести поверху, то обект `new tFpdi()` может кирилицу вывести, а подгрузить pdf не удается.

```
<?php 
use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
if ( isset($_GET['DOK']) && !empty($_GET['DOK']) ) 
{
    $file = 'media/' . url_decode($_GET['DOK']);
    if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'pdf') {
        require_once('includes/TFPDF/fpdf.php');
        require_once('includes/FPDI/src/autoload.php');
        require('includes/TFPDF/tfpdf.php');

        //$pdf = new Fpdi();
        $pdf = new TFPDF();

        $pdf->AddPage();
        //$pdf->setSourceFile($file);
        //$idx=$pdf->importPage(1);
        //$pdf->useImportedPage($idx,10,10,210);
        //$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);

        $pdf->AddFont('DejaVuSansCondensed','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
        $pdf->SetFont('DejaVuSansCondensed','',8);

        $pdf->SetTextColor(0,143,159);
        $str = 'Дата видруку.'. GetCurrentTime();
        //$str =  mb_convert_encoding($str, 'Windows-1251','UTF-8');
        $pdf->Cell(2,2,$str);
        $pdf->Output();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: tFpdi выводит кирилицу... В какой кодировке она попадает в файл pdf? Может её и указать в mb_convert_encoding?

Comment: @nick_n_a, писал `mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');` перед выводом. крякозябры

Comment: проверьте пути до шрифтов. может просто шрифт не подтягивается

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, где именно надо смотреть пути, в каком файле?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, Вы правы, не было шрифта. Использовал инструкцию http://www.cyberforum.ru/post13314998.html